# RPC lib in multilanguage

Tags: c#, c++, xml-rpc, rpc

I search for RPC lib that support client or server in C++ and C#. So i can make client in C++ and talk to server written in C#.
I do not know if Microsoft RPC allow this, Protocol Buffers or MsgPack.

Comment: Use COM, it is one level up from RPC and supported by both C++ and C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Thrift provides a mechanism for defining "services" in any language and accessing that service. There are resources for developing services in both c++ and c#:

c++: http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC%2B%2B

c#: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2008/08/29/c-thrift-examples/

Alternatively, although it's not "cool", there are xml-rpc clients for both c# and c++

c#: http://www.xml-rpc.net/

c++: http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/

Both are mature and work well, so it should be trivial to get up and running. There are, obviously, more advanced protocols such as the aforementioned [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) and [MsgPack](http://msgpack.org/) however neither seems to have RPC capable clients for your target language. The same goes for [Bert](http://bert-rpc.org/) (of GitHub fame) and [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/) (the apache foundations attempt.)